# Servicestack v. 3.9.18 Authenticate attribute does not appear to work anymore

Tags: authentication, servicestack

Just upgraded to servicestack.mvc v. 3.9.18 to fix some null ref exception error, but now the AuthenticateAttribute does not seem to have any effect anymore. I have this action in a controller:

```
[Authenticate]
public ActionResult Index() {
    var authSession = AuthSession;
    return View(); // <-- When I break here, I can see that AuthSesison is null
}
```

When I set a breakpoint and run with cleared cookies, I can break in this method and see that authSession is null. This should not happen because the Authenticate attribute should have redirected the action to the LoginRedirectUrl, or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it was a logic bug introduced with a recent commit that was just [fixed in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/271) and available in NuGet from [v3.9.19+](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Mvc/3.9.19)